# Data from factory is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to play with angularJS.

I wrote this easy example :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory( 'Data' , function() {
    return { message: "I'm data from a service" } 
});
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}
function SecondCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = Data; 
}
```

but i get the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: Data is not defined
```

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Data` which you never defined in the global scope.

Instead, since you defined it with Angular's dependency injection mechanism:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory( 'Data' , function() {
    return { message: "I'm data from a service" } 
});

// angular will figure it out based on parameter name
myApp.controller("FirstCtrl",function($scope,Data) { 
    $scope.data = Data;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRE9L/)

Comment: @Or.Ron glad to help. Worth mentioning http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 since you can't really minify controllers with parameter name based injection like that (you can pass the service name around as a string). Also - a good tutorial about injection http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-injectors

Answer (score 1):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory( 'Data' , function() {
    return { message: "I'm data from a service" } 
});
```